# How to copy a cstring parameter value to a local cstring in C++ function?

Tags: c++

I'm struggling with C++ passing arguments through a function!

Suppose the following function declaration:

```
void functionname (char * myvar) {

   char * ptf;
   ptf = strtok(myvar,"=");

}
```

The cstring **myvar** is passed by reference as is the case for any array passed in a C++ function, right?

But how to make a local copy of the **myvar** variable, that my me modified within the function?

The problem is that the use of the statement "ptf = strtok(myvar,"=");" modifies myvar!

Comment: Initialise a `std::string` with the array which `myvar` points to the first element of: `std::string local_string(myvar);`.

Comment: The problem is that strtok's first parameter must be a char *!

Answer (score 1):

You first need to clear up what you mean.

When you say `myvar` is passed "by reference", you're using the C terminology. You are using *reference semantics* for the array of characters, yes, but you're not passing by reference. In C++, we have reference types for which we use the phrase "passing by reference". Here you have a pointer type. You are passing the pointer by value.

Now you ask "How do I make a local copy of `myvar`?" If I interpret your question literally, then it's as simple as doing:

```
char* anothervar = myvar;
```

I have copied the value of `myvar` to `anothervar`. They still, however, point at at the same array of characters.

If instead you wanted to copy the contents of the string to another array, you would need to use something like `strcpy` and perform some dynamic allocation, but this is very poor C++ style. Instead, you should be using `std::string` throughout. Your function becomes a lot simpler when it is this:

```
void functionname(std::string myvar) {
  std::string anothervar = myvar;
}
```

(Although there's no good reason for copying from `myvar` to `anothervar` since `myvar` is already a copy of the string being passed to it)

I wrote an article recently on [avoiding raw pointers](http://josephmansfield.uk/articles/avoiding-ambiguity-raw-pointers.html) and one of the sections covers C-style strings and why `std::string` is so much better.

Comment: Within the function functionname I use the strtok function like which needs a char * as its first parameter, so using std::string is not an option!

Comment: I would recommend using C++ string parsing utilities, rather than `strtok`. How you do that depends on what you're doing. You can probably do what you want with an `std::istringstream`.

Comment: Switched to std::string library tools!

Answer (score -1):

> The cstring `myvar` is passed by reference as is the case for any array passed in a C++ function, right?

No. It is passed by value in this case.

> But how to make a local copy of the myvar variable, that my me modified within the function?

```
void functionname (char * myvar) {

   std::string::size_type len = strlen(myvar);
   char *temp = new char[len+1];
   strcpy(temp, myvar);
   temp = strtok(temp, "=");
   //....
}
```

Comment: @Mankarse I can't see anything he mention an array except for quoting what the OP said?

Comment: I think I have to return to the very basics of function, pointers and string in C++! Thanks for all the answers!

Comment: @g.verhaag: This answer is unlikely to be actually useful. Array new is pretty much a misfeature of C++. If you use the code in this answer, your code is very likely to have memory leaks (the only way to avoid leaks in the general case is to surround the whole thing in `try catch`, or to write a class that properly manages the resources in its destructor and its copy/move operators). `std::string` is the tool that you need, not `new[]`.

Comment: @Mankarse; *This answer is unlikely to be actually useful. Array new is pretty much a misfeature of C++.*:  Write a letter to C++ standard team to remove `new` from C++ and I will stop using it.

Comment: Indeed the problem of a changed myvar variable after the function "functioname" was called remains!

Comment: @g.verhaag: In that case, you are probably doing something wrong. You should be using `temp` in the function, not `myvar`. The problem with this answer is that the memory allocated by `new char[len+1]` is likely to leak, not that it doesn't make a local copy of the contents of `myvar`.